# Is a multiplexed system/address bus slower?

Tags: memory, bus

When a address bus is multiplexed it typically send addresses in two consecutive parts.
Thus for a 32 bit bus one only need 16 wires.

Typically, (if I get this correct):

4 bit bus:

```
  +-------------+            +-------------+
  |             +----1------->             |
  |             |            |             |
  |             +----0------->             |
  |             |            |             |
  |             +----0------->             |
  |             |            |             |
  |             +----1------->             |
  +-------------+            +-------------+
```

4 bit multiplexed

```
  +-------------+            +-------------+
  |             |            |             |
  |             +----0---1--->             |
  |             |            |             |
  |             +----1---0--->             |
  |             |            |             |
  +-------------+            +-------------+
```

As there is a problem with memory speed vs CPU capability doesn't a multiplexer cause
speed penalty? Is it a physical constraints issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on the bus speed.

If both are say 500Mhz then yes the effective speed is 50% for the second example.

If #1 is 500Mhz and #2 is 1000Mhz then the transfer speeds are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I read this, [Address bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_bus), while looking into CPU, MMU, buses etc. I'm still not sure why it is done, if it is physical constraints or other. But it also seems like this is off topic. If this Q is not HW related I do not know what is.